# How to highlight javascript syntax inside a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I have a bit of a unique problem. I'm currently storing blog posts in markdown syntax and am dynamically rendering them in React using a markdown-to-jsx package. So I get the entire blog post as a giant string and render it in a component like this

```
<Markdown>{ this.state.text }</Markdown>
```

This works fine except for the code blocks that I am trying to highlight with JavaScript syntax. My code elements appear as follows

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-javascript">
    "import React from 'react';
     import './style.css';

     export default class Blog extends React.Component {
       render() {
         return <h1>React Router is working!</h1>;
       }
     }"    
  </code>
</pre>
```

I'm using PrismJS for the syntax highlighting which follows the same class naming format that I have here, but the entire code block is inside of a string due to the markdown-to-jsx converter. I believe the code would be highlighted correctly if it weren't for the string but I don't know how to get around it. I've tried multiple markdown converters and they all use strings inside the HTML elements, and I haven't been able  to find another syntax highlighter that would solve the problem. Should I try storing my blog posts in a different way? Is there another way around this? Any advice would be appreciated.